# Can I upgrade my save games?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I want to upgrade my current game running under version 0.31.25 to the latest version 0.34.02. Is there a safe way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't. The last two update are not savegame compatible ,0.31 to 0.34.01 because of the mass of changes, 0.34.01 to 0.34.02 because of corrupted savegames:

> Toady One The first bugfix release has arrived. Unfortunately, you'll have to restart -- even if your save seems fine, it's likely that it is dying a slow death due to corrupted buildings.

Comment: Hopefully someone will eventually make a utility of some sort that can upgrade them, if that's even possible. I'm holding onto a really nice 31.25 fortress in the hopes that they do.

Comment: That's very unlikely. It's not just the fort that need to be changed, a lot of thing in the world are different. I don't think there is a way to "convert" anythin.

Comment: Hm, alright. I thought something might be able to go through the save files and replace any save code that's changed with the new versions.

Comment: That's certainly possible, @SaintWacko, but highly improbable, due to the amount of work involved. Perhaps it is time for that fortress to have some Fun?

Comment: @kotekzot, it's really just getting started, although Fun wouldn't be too hard, considering it's built into the side of a volcano :D  Well, I suppose I'll have a pretty good chance of Fun when I build my steam cannons.

Comment: Hah, then I guess I'll just have my Fun with the old one (seems to be eminent) and then move on to the latest stable 0.34.

Thanks!